# I want to export 200k records from data base as a .xlsx file using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to export 200k records from database as a .xlsx file. I am using Apache POI.  I am getting broken pipe exception after 20 minutes

```
file = File.createTempFile("Rule_File", ".xlsx");           
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);            
long heapSize = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();                
long freeSize = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();             
long totalSize = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();              
System.out.println("Heap Size = " + heapSize);                  
System.out.println("freeSize = " + freeSize);               
System.out.println("totalSize = " + totalSize);                
// ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));           
//workbook.write(out);
```

Comment: So where is the code that retrieves the data from the database and stores it into the output file? And which DBMS and JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: Just a suggestion, in Squirrel you have a tool that can extract directly from the DB to a excel file. (I assume similar functionality exists in other tools as well)

Comment: Does excel support these many rows? There is a limit to it.

Comment: You could try this lib, it's designed to export large amount of data https://github.com/firegloves/MemPOI

Answer (score 1):

I guess the socket to the DB makes a timeout after 20 minutes.

Either configure a longer timeout if possible. Or you might be able to run the scripts in smaller chunks that runs in less than 20 minutes and then append the results?